# android start new thread call JNI function crashed

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-camera2, java-threads

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProcessWithQueue mprocessWithQueue;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<byte []> mframeQueue;
    private NDKUtils ndk = new NDKUtils();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mframeQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        mprocessWithQueue = new ProcessWithQueue(mframeQueue);
        ...
    }

    public class ProcessWithQueue extends Thread {
        private LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> mQueue;

        public ProcessWithQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> frameQueue) {
            mQueue = frameQueue;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                byte[] frameData = null;
                try {
                    frameData = mQueue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(frameData !=  null){
                    processFrame(frameData);
                }
            }
        }

        private void processFrame(byte[] tmpBytes) {
            //call JNI...
            //...
            int[] res = ndk.handleImg(pix,w,h)
            //...
        }
    }

    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                ...
            //int [] res = ndk.handleImg(pix,w,h)
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

......JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_magicing_eigenndk_NDKUtils_handleImg(
      JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jintArray buf, int w, int h) {
  jint *cbuf;
  cbuf = env->GetIntArrayElements(buf, JNI_FALSE );
  if (cbuf == NULL) {
      return 0;
  }
  Mat srcMat(h, w, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *) cbuf);

  Mat dstMat1;
  .....
  jintArray rst = env->NewIntArray(rst_size+2);

  env->SetIntArrayRegion(rst,0,rst_size+2,temp);

  env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(buf, cbuf, 0);
    return rst;
}
```

I create a new thread to handle the preview images from `camera2`, and the handle function is from JNI. When it comes to call the JNI, it crashed.
As you see , If I call it from main thread It runs well. But that makes the page not fluent.

Comment: post the stacktrace...

Comment: you created a new `HandleImage` then called the `processImage()` function directly

Comment: @JohnJoe    `I/Queue processing ...: handling one frame    
    A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7f7ee76000 in tid 13587 (Thread-1735)`

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz It doesnot work,and the stacktrace is same as the error I post above

Comment: maybe you dont have proper permissions for camera? this error means null pointer, we need more info/jni code

Comment: @V-master That isn't the permission reason .I updated the code above.

Comment: Where do you actually populate the queue? Also, where in the native code does the crash occur (which line of code)?

Comment: Not only it is not clear how the queue is populated, it isn't clear what actually works 'from main thread'. For starters, camera2 typically creates its own handler thread for onImageAvailable callbacks.